# where is the sku of prestashop products saved

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

i am using PrestaShop v1.6.1.4. I want to get sku of any product using custom query. But i am unable to find SKU column in the prestashop database tables. if anyone can please tell me where is the sku of products is saved in the tables i.e which table and column name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prestashop does not call SKUs as SKU. It is "reference".
You can find products table -> reference